# how to use country names or cultures in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

I'm using ChatGPT to help write an essay about learning foreign cultures.

ChatGPT wrote this:

> learn how to greet someone in **Arabic**, how to use gestures in **Italian**,
> how to avoid taboo topics in **Chinese** or how to show respect in **Thai**

But I think it's wrong.
If **Italian** here is an adjective meaning the Italian culture, how can a preposition precede an adjective?
If **Italian** here is a noun meaning the language, how can we use gestures(which I think is only non-verbal) in a language?

Then I rewrite:

> learn how to greet someone in **an Arab country**, how to use gestures in **Italy**,
> how to avoid taboo topics in **China** or how to show respect in **Thailand**

The problem with this version is that it does not address the situation where we meet an Italian in our home country.

Comment: ChatGPT is rubbish. It is able to produce, not coherent text, but what _looks like_ coherent text. For this reason, language learners should not rely on it. For example, as you have realised, gestures are made with the hands, not the mouth, so you can't make them 'in Italian'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for confirming. I think I've got my rewrite: learn how to greet an Arab, navigate Italian culture, avoid taboo topics with the Chinese, or respect Thai customs.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to try learn anything is very dangerous ground. ChatGPT doesn't know truth from fiction. It will give just as authoritative-sounding an answer to absolute garbage as it will to provable fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence:

- Greeting someone in an Arab country might be primarily non-verbal
- Gestures could also be non-verbal/not accompanied by words
- Taboo topics would tend to be taboo for a culture regardless of the language being spoken (e.g. Consider a bilingual country)
- How to show respect in Thailand I assume is by some kind of bow, etc., and is not related to the language.

In the second question all the words mean **languages**. We do not say 'Arabic' if we mean 'Arabic culture' or 'Arab culture'. So the second question is entirely restricted to teaching those specific topics in those languages, whereas the first is more to do with etiquette in those **countries**.

Therefore the second sentence those words are all nouns referring to those languages. And in the first all nouns for those countries.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something from your answer. I switched the position of the two sentences after your answer.